# Jenkins, Gradle : How to publish Dependency report to Sonar Dashboard

Tags: jenkins, gradle, sonarqube, maven-dependency-check-plugin

Currently we're using Jenkins free style job for **Gradle project** and using following commands to run Sonar and Dependencycheck

```
./gradlew clean build sonarqube dependencyCheckAnalyze \
```

and I'm getting following message

Analyzing `/opt/jenkins_slave_home/workspace/AA/package-lock.json` - however, the node_modules directory does not exist. Please run `npm install` prior to running dependency-check
Generating report for project AA_ArbitraryBuild
Found 0 vulnerabilities in project AA

and we can able to see a file inside "ws/build/reports/" but it dint scanned anything.

Following are the "build.gardle" file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url artifactoryRepoUrl }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.7'
        classpath 'org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:6.0.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'org.owasp.dependencycheck'

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.projectName', sonarProjectName
        property 'sonar.projectKey', sonarProjectKey
        property 'sonar.host.url', sonarHostUrl
        property 'sonar.login', sonarAuthToken
        property 'sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath', sonarDependencyCheckReport
        property 'sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath', sonarDependencyCheckHTMLReport
    }
}
```

Can you plz help on what are the additional steps that I need to add.

Comment: Does your project have any javascript files or using nodejs? If yes, then if you want them to scan using SonarQube or want to exclude them ?

Comment: Yes Sourav, we've node files and we need to scan them with SonarQube

Comment: Then, before the sonar scan stage, you need to run  `npm install` as suggested in the error as well.

Comment: I can able to see report in <JenkinsWorkspace>/builds/reports/dependency-check-report.html 
but not able to publish into Sonar Dashboard

Comment: dependencyCheckAnalyze must be run before sonarqube as you want the report files to exist before upload to sonar.

Answer (score 0):

You've got all you need to push result to sonar. Make sure that you provide right path for your owasp vulnerabilities report for sonar plugin. It's *sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath* and should point to *build/reports* directroy, and if you produce html report file you can point it with *sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath*.

Comment: In newer versions of the dependencycheck plugin, they've deprecated the reportPath and replaced it with a specific jsonReportPath  

XML reports have been deprecated as well.